# Changed Program Files now Window Updates fail

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Is there any fix for Window Updates when you change the program files to another drive?

[image: This is the registry change]

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, you can't mess with key Windows internal configurations like [the location of Program Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/933700/microsoft-does-not-support-changing-the-location-of-the-program-files), if changing that location were that easy Windows would offer an option for doing that. This is like opening your car hood, moving a few thinks around and then wondering why the car had an odd behavior after that.

The solution is revert to the original configuration and hope that it didn't messed other things. This configuration can be only changed when installing Windows (although you need professional tools for doing that, and maybe a Pro or Enterprise version of Windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, a [symbolic link](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx) may help you. 
Revert your registry changes and create the symbolic link at the original position of Program Files, pointing to your new location. If this alone doen't work, check the permissions on the link and on the new destination since Windows can be very picky about that, just compare with an unmodified version of Windows.

Something like this should be the command

```
C:/>mklink /D "Program Files (x86)" "D:\Program Files (x86)"
```

Even if it seems to work at the first place, you still could experience some nasty bugs since this is not intended to be done.